# Google Cast icon doesn't show

Tags: java, android, xml, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to integrate Google Cast on my application, but the cast icon doesn't show on my `Toolbar`.

Here is the step what I've tried.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;
```

**`onCreate()`**

```
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance( getApplicationContext() );
        mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                .addControlCategory(
                        CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("MYAPPID"))
                .build();
        mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback();
```

**`onResume()`**

```
    mMediaRouter.addCallback( mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN );
```

**`onCreateOptionsMenu()`**

```
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.media_route_menu_item );
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider( mediaRouteMenuItem );
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector( mMediaRouteSelector );
```

This **Callback** class:

```
class MediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected( MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info ) {

    }
}
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="Chromecast"
   app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

I also tried using the default receiver.

I read that you have to have a Google Cast device so that the icon is visible, there would be a way to test the application without having a device?

Comment: Did you find any other solution ?

Comment: No, please help me!

Comment: i did search a further and only option currently is to have a device as mentioned in answer, though if you find something please update here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have read it right, you cannot see the icon without the `ChromeCast` device being in the same network as your device is in,

You can look for `LeapCast` [here](https://github.com/dz0ny/leapcast), but the repo says that its no longer supported, you can also look for **AllCast** and see if it fits your needs

Comment: I 've installed all cast but how do I register the APP_ID or DeviceID in Cast Developer Console , or alternatively how do I test the application with all cast ??

Comment: instead you can use the `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`, so you can use the Default Receiver so you will not need to register application for testing

Comment: Yes but the problem is not solved..I can't try the application

Comment: Did you try with `LeapCast` ? i know its deprecated, but other than this two you will need chromecast device itself,

Comment: It is blocked.. "This project no longer works because Google locked down entire API"

Comment: Yes thats case so as i said in the answer you will need the device itself, i have recently faced the similar thing but couldn't test without the device , see if you could come up with something that does that :)

Comment: ok let's say that I buy her the cast and register the device on the cast developers , then when the app will be on playstore how shall I do? you need to record something on cast developers ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113607/discussion-between-satyen-udeshi-and-michele-lacorte).

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi I have followed the steps as mentioned in [https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#add_a_cast_button] for adding a cast button, but it does'nt show up in my activity.

Comment: @Ashwini Kutre do you have a chrome cast device in the same network in which your device is ? If not then cast button will not show up.

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi : Both are connected to same network. But the icon does'nt show up

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi I've also the same problem i.e. icon is not visible in the toolbar. Can you help me for the same, if you found the solution? I've tried Reflector [http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/mac-and-windows/] and by this YouTube app started showing the icon but google cast sample sender app didn't. Thanks!